# How to increase the default font size on a Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, fonts, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the system font size in OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/253973/how-can-i-change-the-system-font-size-in-osx)

I just bought a MBP and the default font size is killing my eyes. How can I increase it?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/253973/how-can-i-change-the-system-font-size-in-osx