# How to make the text bigger and still crisp on Mac OS X with high resolution by default?

Tags: display, resolution, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro with display 1680 x 1050.  The text displayed on the OS interface windows generally seems too small for my eyes.  I'd like to set them generally bigger somehow.  If I choose the smaller resolutions in Preference>Display, e.g. 1600x1250, the texts actually look not crisp any more. Is making the resolution lower the correct way? If not, what's the proper way?

Comment: The system/menu text on my macbook pro is physically about 2mm high, or what the publishing world calls 6 point font.  One might try scaling the resolution until it is usable (but blurry) size, then measuring what size it is physically.   The the question might be 'how do I get crisp, 12 point system fonts on my mac?'  I'm afraid the answer is "No, you can't."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is change the DPI used to draw the font, and make it larger. Sadly, there's no easy way to do this. You'll find the following questions and their answers pertinent to your quest:

[Change DPI on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/13412/change-dpi-on-osx)

[How can I change the system font size in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/253973/how-can-i-change-the-system-font-size-in-os-x)

Comment: Any change for Mountain Lion?

Comment: Any updates on this with the latest Maverick?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the resolution as high as possible, and use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to adjust font sizes.

In most applications, you can make text larger simply by using the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (That is the command key, and the plus sign). Reverse what you have done by using the minus sign instead.

This will work in all major browsers, in the terminal app, skype, and any other native app. You can keep the resolution as high as you want. This only affects the font sizing, and should be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening System Preferences > Universal Access > Seeing.

Comment: Tried it.  The result isn't ideal.  When zoomed in/out, it creates too much extra operations in the workflow.  On a smaller Macbook Pro with default resolution 1440x900, the default text size on interfaces look just OK to me.

Comment: Any settings I could adjust on the bigger-screen Macbook Pro so the text just look bigger **constantly**?

Answer (score 0):

After awhile of staring at the screen, my eyes just don't want to focus so damn cloe anymore (I'm farsighted) so in like Textedit, you can just hit command plus key (shift is unnessacary) works in all the browsers adn stuff too, the only app it doesn't seem to work in is Xcode, and you can change the font size in Xcode > Preferences > Fonts & Colors click in the window, hit command and a on the keyboard to select all, then change the font size.